# In TFS, how do I override the "keep items checked out when checking in" setting for a check in?

Tags: tfs

In Team Foundation Server, I want to use the setting to "keep items checked out when checking in" active, but I will eventually want to do a check in where it does not check it back out automatically.

How do I accomplish this without changing the setting every time? Is there a shortcut key I can use (pressing shift while checking in or something)?

I am also willing to do the reverse and keep the setting off and do something extra when I want to check in and keep the file checked out. I just don't want to have to change the setting every time.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the scenario you are trying to solve?  Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to override the setting at checkin time.  If you explain your scenario though, there may be a better way to accomplish this altogether.  Why exactly do you want to keep the files checked out?

Comment: I am not sure why the "why" I want to do this is relevant. the fact that there is a global setting (Tools>Options>Environment>"keep items checked out when checking in" box) tells me that I am not the only one that wants to do this. If you must have a why, maybe I am working on multiple work items that are in the same set of files, and I want to do a check in after each feature, but I don't want to have to go looking for the files again to re-check them out. The problem I have is that I don't want to ALWAYS keep checked out. How do I tell it "on this check in, don't keep checked out"?

Comment: The reason why I was trying to understand your scenario more is because there currently isn't a shortcut for toggling the setting in question at check-in time but I was still hoping to try to help you out. For instance, if you are always keeping files checked out because you didn't like how long it takes for VS to automatically check out files when you start typing I was going to tell you about the "asynch checkout" feature we built in VS2012 that solves this issue.

Comment: Also, because I am the development lead for TFS Version Control it is good for me to understand why people are trying to do what they are doing.  If you presented a really compelling scenario for why having this option would be useful then I could push for it in our next release.  I'll at least point you to our UserVoice site so that you can make and vote for the suggestion there if it is something you'd really like to see in the product: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30925-team-foundation-server

Comment: There are a variety of reason's why I might want to keep them checked out. What I said above. I might also only be partially complete, but what I have is testable, so I want that to go in. It would probably be helpful for you to know that I am working with database objects. So I might be working with a table, a stored procedure, and a trigger that are in three different file paths in TFS. It is a pain to go to all three places to do that checkout. At my last place we used perforce for our source control, and I used this functionality all the time. Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'll put here what I put in the comments above so that this has an answer to it.  Unfortunately there is no way to do this today in TFS.  If this is something people are passionate about then I suggest they vote for it on our [UserVoice site](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30925-team-foundation-server).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I made that suggestion at the user voice site.